how to upgrade Browser for SQL Server 2022 16.0.1000.6 and Microsoft VSS Writer for SQL Server 2022
We need to upgrade ‘Browser for SQL Server 2022 16.0.1000.6’ and ‘Microsoft VSS Writer for SQL Server 2022 16.0.1000.6’ in order to be SOC2 compliant, we use SentinelOne application vulnerability scan reports as SOC2 evidence and SentinelOne is reports these as vulnerable and so we are forced to remediate.
We have Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU14-GDR) (KB5042578) - 16.0.4140.3 (X64) installed on top of Windows Server 2022 Standard
We bought the server(s) from Dell with Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU14-GDR) (KB5042578) - 16.0.4140.3 (X64) installed on top of Windows Server 2022 Standard and we have access to the installation files for both Windows Server 2022 Standard and Microsoft SQL Server 2022 however they are both the same versions as what we currently have.
We installed the cumulative update(s) SQLServer2022-KB5038325-x64.exe but this did not upgrade Browser for SQL Server 2022 or Microsoft VSS Writer for SQL Server, after some research it seems that the way it is done is buy upgrading to the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server 2022, have I missed something? … we are surely not the first to be in this situation and would appreciate some guidance.
Am I correct in thinking that the only way is to get ahold of a current installation ISO of Microsoft SQL Server 2022?
We installed the cumulative update(s) SQLServer2022-KB5038325-x64.exe but this did not upgrade Browser for SQL Server 2022 or Microsoft VSS Writer for SQL Server, after some research it seems that the way it is done is buy upgrading to the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server 2022, have I missed something?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There's CU15 now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate15 why not try it out
